# How to get STS/Eclipse JS editor to accept JSX?

Tags: eclipse, reactjs, jsx, spring-tool-suite

Doing React development in STS (within a JS project) is an exercise in ignoring "red underlined problems."  Although the JS editor does OK with ES6 and React in general, once a React Component is defined with JSX then it's as red as the balance sheet of an '09 stock trader.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any react development myself, but did you try this plugin? Maybe it helps: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript-ide

Comment: I do have this installed. It didn't help.  Perhaps there is some configuration I need to do...  All I do when writing code is use file->new-> JS file and go to work.  I'm assuming TypesScript-IDE then works through the JS editor.  OK.  I see there is a file->new->TypeScript Project.  I'm kinda sad I've got to make another project but I'm willing to give it a try. :-)